# Changing references style using biblatex with biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, pdftex, biber

## What I Want

I want my reference output to look like this for all online resources who do have all the values to fill out all of the following fields:

```
{NAME},{First Name},{Publishing year}. Titel des Artikels: {Subtitle}. In: {Name of the newspaper} [online]. {Publishing date of the article}[Zugriff am: {tt.mm.jjjj}]. Verfügbar unter: {DOI | URL}.
```

Note: Everything in {} should be replaced with an actual value.

[An example:](https://www.thesius.de/blog/articles/zitieren-informatik-ieee-din-iso-690/)

> BRÖHM, Alexandra, 2016. Biometrische Systeme: Ein Passwort kann man
>   ändern, die eigene Iris nicht. In: Süddeutsche Zeitung [online].
>   01.09.2016 [Zugriff am: 21.08.2017]. Verfügbar unter: http://www.sueddeutsche.de/digital/biometrische-systeme-ein-passwort-kann-man-aendern-die-eigene-iris-nicht-1.3144344.

## The Code

I'm using Overleaf with `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)`.
In my preamble I've got the following code:

```
%Bibliography management 
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
    sorting=ynt,
    dashed=false,
    autolang=other,
    bibencoding=UTF8,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\bibliography{references}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

%Silence annoying warnings e.g.: Package biblatex Warning: File 'german-ieee.lbx' not found!
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{biblatex}{File 'ngerman-ieee.lbx'}
\WarningFilter{biblatex}{File 'german-ieee.lbx'}
\WarningFilter{biblatex}{File 'english-ieee.lbx'}

% for using multiple files
\usepackage{subfiles}
```

## What I've tried

I've tried to use `\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{Zugriff am Tag: \bibstring{urldate}\space#1}}`, but this always gives me the error `Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'urldate' undefined at entry [...]` and I've searched for a style or package which does this by default for me, but could not find any.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed no `biblatex` bibstring called `urldate`. Did you perhaps mean `urlseen`? But you probably don't need it, as you've already hardcoded `Zugriff am Tag`.

Therefore

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{Zugriff am Tag:\space#1}}
```

should work; though you might want to make things a bit more streamlined with

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=ieee,...]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  urlseen = {Zugriff am}
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}}
```

Note that you don't need `\bibliography{references}`: just `\addbibresource{reference.bib}` is enough.

Comment: I slightly reworded the first sentence to avoid mentioning 'label' and 'key' because those words could be mistaken for technical terms like *entry key* and *(citation/alphabetic/numeric) label*. While I was at it I also moved the colon from the bibstring to the field format (usually there is no trailing punctuation in bibstrings). Feel free to revert this edit if you disagree.

Comment: @moewe Not at all, thanks for the edit!

Comment: Could you please clarify why `urldate` is no biblatex string? I can use such a string in my .bib file without any errors or warnings. I'm also wondering how I can get the URL part working as it would have to be moved to the end and this (online) part is only visible with `langid={English}` which does of course not work with the `DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}`.